# Can't view Google Maps in HTML, Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, cordova

I'm trying to displayGoogle Maps on a html page in cordova.
The example code I'm trying to replicate is this one: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple?hl=it
Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/google_map.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>        
</body>
```

index.js (I used some alert() and every method was called)

```
var app = {

initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},

onDeviceReady: function() {
    toIndex();
}    
};

$(document).ready( function(){
    app.initialize();   
});

function toIndex(){
    google_map.init();
}
```

google_map.js
the class which take care of the map

```
var google_map = (function(){

var _map;
var _$map_canvas;

function init(){

    _$map_canvas = $('.app').find('#map-canvas');

    var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    };
    _map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

}

function getMap(){
    return _map;
}

return {
    init:init,
    getMap:getMap
}
})();
```

and the index.css file

```
#map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
```

}

Instead of displaying the map, I see a white page.

Second question:
code here: http://jsfiddle.net/qbddfdk7/1/
This one doesn't work too, the problem is at line 14:
if I change it from

```
map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, mapOptions);
```

to

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

It will work, but I can't undesrstand why.

Comment: Comment to second question : define or initialzie the variable map_canvas inside initialize() function. like here  http://jsfiddle.net/qbddfdk7/3/ otherwise it will outside the scope hence null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the  css, in eclipse I corrcted the css to this:

```
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

I'm new to web languages and I didn't know that I had to write css even for the hmtl and the body tag, as you can see those tag are missing from the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your second question is a timing issue.

You see, your inline javascript is in the `<head>`, so at the time `var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');` runs, the element with the id `map-canvas` is not loaded yet, so `var map_canvas` is set to null.

Moving the `<script>` tag to the bottom of the `<body>` element solves this issue. [I've updated your jsFiddle accordingly.](http://jsfiddle.net/qbddfdk7/2/)

As for your first issue, try [Chrome Remote Debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) if available, or [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/). These will help you find the source of your problem.

Comment: thank you for your help, I've forked your code trying to use jquery to extract the variable but it doesn't work.  Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/pjg99jc2/1/, do you have any clue?

Comment: @AR89 2 issues with the code: 1-the `script` tags were nested, but shouldn't be. 2- Google Maps expects a DOM node, not a jQuery object, so a `get()` call was needed. [Updated the code on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/pjg99jc2/3/)

Answer (score 1):

I've had no luck using their recommendation to use percentages for the map-canvas.  To ensure everything is working fine, hard-code the div tag to a fixed width and height.

Once you have the map displayed, then you'll need to write javascript to adjust the style width and height during the pagecreate or pageinit.  You can then change the same properties during the orientationchange event.

There are several articles on the best way to find the screen size.  I'm using:

```
function effectiveDeviceWidth(factor) {

    var deviceWidth = window.orientation == 0 ? window.screen.width : window.screen.height;
    // iOS returns available pixels, Android returns pixels / pixel ratio
    // http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/07/more_about_devi.html
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') >= 0 && window.devicePixelRatio) {
        deviceWidth = deviceWidth / window.devicePixelRatio;
    }
    return parseInt(deviceWidth) * factor + 'px';
}
function effectiveDeviceHeight(factor) {
    var deviceHeight = window.orientation == 0 ? window.screen.height : window.screen.width;
    // iOS returns available pixels, Android returns pixels / pixel ratio
    // http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/07/more_about_devi.html
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') >= 0 && window.devicePixelRatio) {
        deviceHeight = deviceHeight / window.devicePixelRatio;
    }
    return parseInt(deviceHeight) * factor + 'px';
}
$('#map-canvas').width(effectiveDeviceWidth(.8));
$('#map-canvas').height(effectiveDeviceHeight(.6));
```

Hope this helps.